# Make Android Activity looks like dialog

Tags: android, user-interface, android-activity

I am trying to open a dialog on widget click. I have solved the problem skinning the activity started on click with `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`. Unfortunately I cannot reach the same look of a dialog.

This is the outcome:

[Dialog from widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZayE.png)

Instead, I would like to reach this result (except for the button, of course):

[Desired dialog from widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6VAn.png)

(the widget dialog you can see keeping the screen pushed)

As you can see there are some differences: the color of the list items, the color of the text and the list item separator. Is there a predefined theme/style to obtain the same look of a standard dialog? If not, what are the steps to follow to reach that result?

I have seen that the widget provided by FoxyRing has the behaviour I would like to have.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Why not use a "traditional" Main Activity with a transparent background layout

and call a standard dialog from it ?

... well if I understood you correctly, that would make the trick in a very easy way, isn't it ?

Comment: It works. I have set up an activity with android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" and then used the simple code to create a list dialog keeping attention to finish the activity on dialog cancel/click.

Answer (score 3):

you could dynamically create the dialog like this:

```
        Context mContext = this;
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.data_dialog);
        dialog.setTitle("Your title");

        AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        AlertDialog alertDialog;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.data_dialog,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.AbsoluteLayout01));

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setView(layout);
        alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        final EditText txtUsername = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);

        final AlertDialog thisDialog = alertDialog;

         Button btnSave = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
         btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {

                String strtxtUsername = txtUsername.getText().toString();

                //do something...

             }
         });
```

To close the dialog, call `thisDialog.dismiss();`

The style looks like the regular Theme.Light.NoTitleBar with a ListView with an Icon and a Title-Text.

Hope that helps!

Comment: The problem is how to call it when a widget is pressed. It should be inside an activity...and an activity must always display something right?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood you then.

Try setting the activity's theme to

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"`

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a far simpler way to do this than what I suggested below.
Have a look at:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html
under the headline "Adding a list".