# show pop-up from background service in android

Tags: android, service, dialog, background

Hi it is possible in android to show pop-up dialog from background running service?
and answer is positive than how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

There are several options. You can use a theme and make an activity look and behave like a dialog (as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394477/make-android-activity-looks-like-dialog)) by setting the `android:theme` attribute of your `<activity>` to `@android:style/Theme.Dialog` or a customized theme in your manifest.

Alternatively, you could create a translucent activity by setting the theme to `@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` and then launch a regular dialog from the activity.  As the comments on one of the answers to the question advise, in this case just make sure to `finish()` the translucent activity whenever the dialog is dismissed.