# Delayed execution in an Android activity

Tags: android, delayed-execution

I would like to trigger showing a dialog X seconds after something happens in an activity (resumed, button clicked, etc.)

- What are my options? (e.g. Thread, [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html))
- Are there special things to note for these options? e.g. do I need to check if the activity is still active?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `handler.postDelayed(runnable, delayedms);`

this is one of the methods, you can also use AlaramManager.

For AlaramManager your activity need not be active. and handler it should be.

Comment: With Handler, how do I verify that the activity is active? With AlarmManager, how do I connect to the correct context (the current active activity) to show the dialog?

Comment: you can use handler.removeCallbacks(runnable) , in your activity onPause() method, which will remove the scheduled operation once your activity is out of focus. As far as the alarm manager is concerned, it is used for notification kind of things, or to do some back ground process, not for your purpose of showing dialog boxes, i think.

Comment: +1, thanks! Could my activity be killed without onPause being called, but with the handler still being active?

Comment: no, onPause() is called, before pausing or killing an activity.

Answer (score 0):

One option I considered: instead of attaching a dialog to an existing view, I can create a transparent view (with `<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394477/make-android-activity-looks-like-dialog/2397346#2397346)) and have it create a dialog.

This is nice since I can create this activity with a delayed intent.

I need to make sure to call `finish()` when the dialog is closed.

I'm not sure how to have this happen only if the original activity is still active.

Comment: Why not just use @android:style/Theme.Dialog?