# White border for AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I need to put a white border around this default dialog box

[image]

Here is the xml code on which I am working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  >

<solid android:color="#000000" />

<stroke
    android:width="25dp"
    android:color="#FFFFFF" />

<corners android:radius="10dp" />

</shape>
```

But it doesn't produce the desired result. The result is coming like this:

[image]

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: btw you can make a custom dialog

Comment: I think your question is something like [this question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394477/make-android-activity-looks-like-dialog

Comment: your question is similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439538/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-alertdialog-title-and-the-color-of-the-line-under

Answer (score -1):

Create a 9-patch image like this

[image]

and apply it in this manner

```
<style name="RunesDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">

        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/cadre_dialogue/>
        ......
</style>
```