# Android set activity size to look like a dialog

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I have an application that records video,what i want is a little window at the top right of the screen (like Skype does).
I am not sure but i think i should resize the activity.
any suggestions ?

thank you

Comment: make your activity, a dialog activity...

Comment: try this ref : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394477/make-android-activity-looks-like-dialog?rq=1

Comment: I have made this as a dialog activity ,and now i need to resize it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can define your activity as dialog in `Manifest` file.

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

Comment: the problem is that there is background behind the dialog. @Godather

Comment: you can change theme accordingly. ex -android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog".

Comment: it doesnt help,i want the camera to be seen at the top right corner,and be able to continue playing with my phone as usual ,like skype @Godfather